# How to get integers from a column from a dataframe

Tags: string, dataframe, integer

I want to get integers from the columns highlighted in the picture.
How do I derive integers from these columns and define a separate column within the dataframe?

[please refer this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dAxY.png)

Answer (score 0):

To get integer from first column, you can write a function and split column values by "of".
Same way, split the column values by "%" and read the first string to get the integer value.